# How to mark multiple contacts to send same text as bcc - feature that exists on Android

Tags: ios

How to mark multiple contacts on iPhone 6 (ios8)for messaging severally the same text as bcc.  This feature exists on Android phones wherein you write text and tick as many contacts you wish and the message goes to each one of them individually.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible on iOS. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Comment: Thanks !   Have escalated to Apple.  Is there any App which can be downloaded to make this feature functional ?